# Take $A^T$ to be an nxm matrix such that $m<n$. How is this inconsistent?

Tags: linear-algebra

My book says "since $ m < n$, the row echelon form of the (n x m) matrix $A^T$ must have a row of zeros."

I have been trying to convince myself of this, but I simply cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

Pivots (or leading $1$, depending on how you call them) in a matrix in a row echelon form belong to different rows *and* different columns.

So there can be at most $m$ pivots in the row echelon form for $A^T$. Rows without a pivot are zero by definition of pivot; so at most $m$ rows can be nonzero.